# Setting DrawMode in ListBox removes horizontal scroll bar

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, scroll, scrollbar

I set the DrawMode in my listbox control to OwnerDrawFixed so that I can color some items. When an item is too long to fit in the horizontal space of the list box no horizontal scoll appears.

How can I make the scrollbar appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should set HorizontalExtent  property of listbox in OwnerDrawFixed mode

```
    listBox1.HorizontalExtent = xx; //xx can be maximum size list box item fills
```

To determine the value that HorizontalExtent should be set to use the following method on the the strings in your list box and get the Width property:

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, listBox1.font)
```

Set HorizontalExtent to the largest Width value that MeasureText returns

Comment: I added an edit to explain what to set HorizintalExtent to. Basically the value of TextRenderer.MeasureText(text,listBox1.font).Width

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [`ListBox.MeasureItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem.aspx) event. See the example in msdn page.

Comment: The event is only raised when the DrawMode property is set to OwnerDrawVariable.