# No horizontal scrollbar when setting ListBox DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed

Tags: c#, listbox

The code below works perfectly to draw text items in my listbox  (articlesLB) to a certain color based on some conditions. But when the text is longer than the size of the listbox, the horizontal scrollbar fails to show. I've implemented the MeasureItemEventHandler and DrawItemEventHandler. Can any one see why this is not working?

```
articlesLB.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
articlesLB.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(articlesLB_MeasureItem);
articlesLB.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(articlesLB_SetColor);

private void articlesLB_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
     int textwidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(articlesLB.Items[e.Index].ToString(), articlesLB.Font).Width;
     articlesLB.HorizontalExtent = textwidth;
}

private void articlesLB_SetColor(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) return;

    //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                  e.Font,
                                  e.Bounds,
                                  e.Index,
                                  e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                  e.ForeColor,
                                  Color.Yellow); //Choose the color

    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();

    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

    // check some boolean flags to see if either is checked

    if (EditAOSideRB.Checked == true || EditAPinSideRB.Checked == true)
    {
        string articleTitle = ((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();

        if (articleTitle.Contains("* ") == true)
        {
            // set the brush to green
            myBrush = Brushes.DarkGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            // set the brush to red
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    // Draw the current item text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(articlesLB.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: Duplicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240608/setting-drawmode-in-listbox-removes-horizontal-scroll-bar

Answer (score -1):

You should set DrawMode to OwnerDrawVariable.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) for ListBox.DrawMode:

> This event is used by an owner-drawn ListBox. The event is only raised
> when the DrawMode property is set to DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed or
> DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable. You can use this event to perform the
> tasks needed to draw items in the ListBox. If you have a
> variable-sized item (when the DrawMode property is set to
> DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable), before drawing an item, the MeasureItem
> event is raised. You can create an event handler for the MeasureItem
> event to specify the size for the item that you are going to draw in
> your event handler for the DrawItem event.

Comment: Setting HorizontalExtent shows it even in OwnerDrawFixed.